# how to add copyright symbol in a highcharts title?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If I add `&copy;` it shows up as `&copy;` instead of the copyright symbol.  Is there any way to add html special chars?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

html entities (`&copy;`) need to be added as innerHTML. For text, use Unicode:

```
alert('\u00A9')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use one of these options.

1. **\251**   is the octal sequence
2. **\xA9**   is the hexadecimal sequence
3. **\u00A9** is the Unicode sequence

for example **alert('\251');**